# Why does this exception not cause a runtime error?

Tags: java, exception

I have the following code in a practice question:

```
public class Test {

    static String s = "";

    public static void m0(int a, int b) { 
        s += a; 
        m2();
        m1(b);
    }

    public static void m1(int i) {
        s += i;
    }

    public static void m2() {
        throw new NullPointerException("aa"); 
    }

    public static void m() {
        m0(1, 2); 
        m1(3);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            m(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

At method m2, when the NullPointerException is thrown, why does it not terminate the thread as I expected? I thought as there was not a try catch block in the same method, it would cause an exception and halt the program.

As I understand it, it has reverted back to the previously called method, m0, when I thought the thrown exception would have halted the program. The end result is that the program prints 1, as the value of s.

Everything I have read so far concerning exceptions doesn't explain this logic, and I can't work it out myself, so I was hoping I could get some help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try debugging?

Comment: exceptions bubble up until they're either `catch`ed or bubble off the top of the execution stack. that means your `catch` in `main()` catches, and does NOTHING, since the catch block is empty. put some output in there (e.g. `System.out.println('Hey, I caught something');` and try again.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker yeah just tried it, it has no problems with compiling or running, it just prints 1

Comment: When you call m2() it throw NPE, you catch it in main() method and then print value of s, which at that point is 1 because of `s += a;` in m0().

Comment: Remove the try-catch in your main, and try again.

Comment: Great comments, worked out that it the catch in my main method is catching it, thanks to your comments. When I added a print.ln to the catch, it printed it the output. When I removed the catch (Exception e) from the main method, it threw a NullPointerException as I expected. The reason I was confused was because the exceptions were name differently, although this didn't make a difference. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when the `NullPointerException` is thrown, why does it not terminate the thread as I expected?

Because the thread is not going to terminate unless the exception travels all the way up the invocation chain.

> I thought as there was not a try catch block in the same method, it would cause an exception and halt the program.

It's not the same method, it's in any of the methods up the chain of invocation - in this case, `main` catches the exception, preventing the thread from terminating.

Answer (score 2):

You are catching the exception in your main method.  Your version just ignores it, the version below would print the exception ...

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        m(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("You are catching: " + e);
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

If you want the program to terminate, do not catch the exception as in the example below:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    m();
    // never reached
    System.out.println(s);
}
```